rails: NameError uninitialized constant
I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to create a custom logger. I've placed my custom logger class in app/custom_logger/custom_log.rb as follows:
module CustomLogger
  class CustomLog
    def self.info
      puts 'called'
    end
  end
end

In my AccountController (app/controllers/account_controller.rb), I'm trying to use this custom logger:
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  def get
    CustomLogger::CustomLog.info
    render status: :ok
  end
end

However, when I send a request to this controller, I get the following error:
uninitialized constant AccountController::CustomLogger

I tried adding include CustomLogger in app/controllers/application_controller.rb and using require_relative '../custom_logger/custom_log.rb', but neither of these approaches worked.

either add app/custom_logger to eager load paths in your config or move customer_logger under app/models/concerns. The classloader doesn't know you've created a new folder under app

That's nice. But it's in no way a logger. In Ruby the basic interface for loggers is provided by the Logger class. Rails provides a spiffed up version as ActiveSupport::Logger. You also do NOT want to autoload a logger if you want to actually be able to use it in for example initializers.

Zeitwerk will expect the path to be "app/custom_logger/custom_logger/custom_log.rb" based on your module nesting.

With this file structure app/custom_logger/custom_log.rb, zeitwerk is expecting you to define CustomLog:
# root directory
#       |
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# app/custom_logger/custom_log.rb
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^
#                      |
class CustomLog # -----'
end

File structure have to correspond to module/class names relative to a root directory. Rails will automatically configure any directory directly under app to be a root directory by adding it to autoload_paths.
If you want to have CustomLogger::CustomLog then you need to make an extra directory under app, name it whatever you like:
# root directory
#      |
# vvvvvvvvvvv
# app/loggers/custom_logger/custom_log.rb
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
#                      |        |
module CustomLogger # -'        |
  class CustomLog   # ----------'
  end
end

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Note, that you cannot use this logger when application is booting up, that goes for all reloadable code (everything in autoload_paths). You could set up autoload_once_paths if you want to use it in an initializer, or you can always put it in your lib directory and require it.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots

What you could do is move custom_logger to lib folder (the path will be lib/custom_logger/custom_log.rb), which is intended for code that doesn't fit into the MVC pattern.
after that you probably will have to restart your server, but worked here.

Rails, at least current versions, autoload any files in folders under the app folder.  Just reboot the app.
